# awk trying to use output as input and erroring

Tags: bash

In the below `awk` I am trying to combine all matching `$4` into a single `$5` (up to the `-`), and average all values in `$7`.  Why is the `awk` complaining about the output not being foung (that is the `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/bedtools/30x/${pref}_genes.txt`).  Thank you :).

**input (`/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/bedtools/30x/*30reads_perbase.txt')**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    1   15
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    2   16
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    3   16
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    4   14 
chr1 976035 976270 chr1:976035-976270 AGRN-9|gc=74.5 1  28
chr1 976035 976270 chr1:976035-976270 AGRN-9|gc=74.5 2   27
chr1 976035 976270 chr1:976035-976270 AGRN-9|gc=74.5 3   27
```

**desired output**

```
chr1:955543-955763 4 AGRN 15
chr1:976035-976270 3 AGRN 27
```

**awk**

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/30x/*30reads_perbase.txt ; do      bname=`basename "$f"`;      pref=${bname%%.txt};      awk '{k=$4 FS $5; a[k]+=$7; c[k]++}
 END{for(k in a)
 split(k,ks,FS);
 print ks[1],c[k],ks[2],a[k]/c[k]}' "$f" > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/30x/"${pref}"_genes.txt; done
```

**current output**

```
chr1:976035-976270 3 AGRN 27.3333
```

Comment: The INPUT is not being found: no file matches `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/bedtools/30x/*30reads_perbase_genes.txt`. Make sure that the files are there. If you want to handle the case when no input file is found the add `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: awk isn't complaining at all, bash is. There is a big hint in the error line `bash: ...`. You could replace the `awk` command with `date` or something and you'd get the same error message.

Comment: There are other bugs here -- you're missing a bunch of quotes, which http://shellcheck.net/ will automatically identify for you -- but the immediate problem is what the prior comments have already identified.

Comment: Thank now I am not getting the desired output and will update my original post with the new `bash` and current output.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the functions substr and match when you are printing the variables:

cat  | awk '{k=$4 FS $5; a[k]+=$7; c[k]++}END{for(k in a)split(k,ks,FS);print ks[1],c[k],substr(ks[2],0,match(ks[2],"-")-1),a[k]/c[k]}'

chr1:955543-955763 4 AGRN 15.25

Comment: Sorry, the beginning of the line I was using cat filename and pipe to awk command.

Comment: That seems to work great, but the actual file I am using is several thousands of lines and it seems to be skipping the first 999 and only using the last record in the file.  Also, can `15.25` be `15`? I will update the post as well.  Thank you :).

Comment: To round, you have to use the printf instead of print:cat filename | awk '{k=$4 FS $5; a[k]+=$7; c[k]++}END{for(k in a)split(k,ks,FS);printf ("%s %d %s %.0f\n",ks[1],c[k],substr(ks[2],0,match(ks[2],"-")-1),a[k]/c[k])}'

Comment: Thank you, not sure why only the last line is used but we will see.  Thank you very much :).